# Ansible: parsing a dictionary recursively

Tags: ansible

I'm struggling to implement something like a "recursive function" in Ansible, but it seems to be a slightly tricky task.

Let's say, I have a tree-like dictionary:

```yaml
tree:
  alpha: 1
  foo/:
    bravo: 2
    bar/:
      charlie: 3
      baz/:
        delta: 4
```

What I need is to parse it, create some entities (let's say, a sub-directory or sub-domain, it doesn't matter what exactly) for each element which name ends with the `/` character and create some other entity (let's say a file or a DNS-record, it doesn't matter as well) for each element which name ends with anything else.

Here's a minimal example of the solution I'm trying to implement.

The `playbook.yaml` file:

```yaml
- hosts:
    - localhost
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: proceed_branch.yaml
      vars:
        tree:
          alpha: 1
          foo/:
            bravo: 2
            bar/:
              charlie: 3
              baz/:
                delta: 4
```

The `proceed_branch.yaml` file:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ tree }}"

- debug:
    msg: "Got {{ item.key }} = {{ item.value }}"
  loop: "{{ tree | dict2items }}"
  when: item.key is not regex('/$')

- include_tasks: proceed_branch.yaml
  vars:
    tree: "{{ item.value }}"
  loop: "{{ tree | dict2items }}"
  when: item.key is regex('/$')
```

And here's what I get as the output:

```
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that
the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [include_tasks] ***********************************************************
Included: /tmp/ansible/proceed_branch.yaml for localhost

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "foo/": {
            "bar/": {
                "baz/": {
                    "delta": 4
                },
                "charlie": 3
            },
            "bravo": 2
        },
        "alpha": 1
    }
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'alpha', 'value': 1}) => {
    "msg": "Got alpha = 1"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'foo/', 'value': {'bravo': 2, 'bar/': {'charlie': 3, 'baz/': {'delta': 4}}}}) 

TASK [include_tasks] ***********************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string ({{ tree | dict2items }}).\nMake sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-': dict2items requires a dictionary, got <class 'ansible.template.AnsibleUndefined'> instead.. dict2items requires a dictionary, got <class 'ansible.template.AnsibleUndefined'> instead.. Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string ({{ tree | dict2items }}).\nMake sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-': dict2items requires a dictionary, got <class 'ansible.template.AnsibleUndefined'> instead.. dict2items requires a dictionary, got <class 'ansible.template.AnsibleUndefined'> instead."}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

What do you think, why `dict2items` gets the "undefined value" at some point?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Here's what I expect to get as the result:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [include_tasks] ***********************************************************
included: /tmp/ansible/proceed_branch.yaml for localhost

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "alpha": 1,
        "foo/": {
            "bar/": {
                "baz/": {
                    "delta": 4
                },
                "charlie": 3
            },
            "bravo": 2
        }
    }
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'alpha', 'value': 1}) => {
    "msg": "Got alpha = 1"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'foo/', 'value': {'bravo': 2, 'bar/': {'charlie': 3, 'baz/': {'delta': 4}}}}) 

TASK [include_tasks] ***********************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'alpha', 'value': 1}) 
included: /tmp/ansible/proceed_branch.yaml for localhost => (item={'key': 'foo/', 'value': {'bravo': 2, 'bar/': {'charlie': 3
, 'baz/': {'delta': 4}}}})

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "bar/": {
            "baz/": {
                "delta": 4
            },
            "charlie": 3
        },
        "bravo": 2
    }
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'bravo', 'value': 2}) => {
    "msg": "Got bravo = 2"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'bar/', 'value': {'charlie': 3, 'baz/': {'delta': 4}}}) 

TASK [include_tasks] ***********************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'bravo', 'value': 2}) 
included: /tmp/ansible/proceed_branch.yaml for localhost => (item={'key': 'bar/', 'value': {'charlie': 3, 'baz/': {'delta': 4}}})

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "baz/": {
            "delta": 4
        },
        "charlie": 3
    }
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'charlie', 'value': 3}) => {
    "msg": "Got charlie = 3"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'baz/', 'value': {'delta': 4}}) 

TASK [include_tasks] ***********************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'charlie', 'value': 3}) 
included: /tmp/ansible/proceed_branch.yaml for localhost => (item={'key': 'baz/', 'value': {'delta': 4}})

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "delta": 4
    }
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'delta', 'value': 4}) => {
    "msg": "Got delta = 4"
}

TASK [include_tasks] ***********************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'delta', 'value': 4}) 
skipping: [localhost]
```

Comment: I think if you want to process a data structure recursively you would be better off moving your logic into Python (e.g. as a custom filter).

Comment: @larsks , I totally agree that it would be more efficient, though I have a feeling that this task could be accomplished with pure Ansible. I even did something similar before, now I'm trying to realise what was the difference in these approaches.

Comment: `for each element which name starts and ends with the / character` <= there are no such keys in your example. You might want to have a look at the [`to_paths` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/to_paths_lookup.html) which could help. But in such case a custom module/filter is probably the best choice as already advised.

Comment: @Zeitounator , sorry, fixed the example.

Comment: There are still no elements which start **and** end with a slash

Comment: @Zeitounator , oh, really. Fixed the problem description as well. It wasn't related to the problem itself, though it could be slightly confusing.

Comment: You should provide an example of expected results. At least one, if there might be more of them.

Comment: @VladimirBotka , right, I've just added such example, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found a pretty ugly solution, though it seems to be working. The point is to add a temporary variable (by setting a fact):

```yaml
- hosts:
    - localhost
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: proceed_branch.yaml
      vars:
        tree:
          alpha: 1
          foo/:
            bravo: 2
            bar/:
              charlie: 3
              baz/:
                delta: 4
```

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ tree }}"

- set_fact:
    __t: "{{ tree }}"

- debug:
    msg: "Got {{ item.key }} = {{ item.value }}"
  loop: "{{ __t | dict2items }}"
  when: item.key is not regex('/$')

- include_tasks: proceed_branch.yaml
  vars:
    tree: "{{ item.value }}"
  loop: "{{ __t | dict2items }}"
  when: item.key is regex('/$')
```

I hate how it looks like, though it works.

If anyone have a better idea, please, be so kind as to share.